# Syncing Tasks from MS Exchange to iPhone

Tags: exchange, iphone

iPhone doesn't ship with an application to manage tasks or to-do lists, so when you sync your phone with an Exchange server, your Tasks don't make it over.

What options exist for syncing Exchange Tasks with the iPhone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update (06/2011):

As of iOS 5, Apple has introduced Reminders, a todo list app that works with Exchange:

http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html#reminders

---

There are many applications available in Apple's App Store that solve this problem. However, they're all paid applications with generally low customer reviews, so be careful when choosing which application you want to purchase. Or buy them all and then post your thoughts here.

---

- [iMExchange](http://web.me.com/rerlsoft/Rerlsoft/Index.html)

  A third-party iPhone application that allows you to add/edit/delete tasks as well as other Exchange data, such as calendar, out of office status, etc. This is a paid app, though a free, read-only version of the app exists (viMLite Viewer) for the purposes of testing your configuration to ensure it works with your Exchange server before purchasing the full version.

  Edit: please refer to Jeff Binder's answer below about this app.
- [TaskTask](http://tasktaskapp.com/)

  Looks good. Two votes for it so far (see below).
- [TaskData](http://www.latenightrobots.com/taskdata/taskdata.html)

  A third-party iPhone application that allows you to add/edit/delete tasks and notes. Works over-the-air via OWA, so no manual syncing is required.  This is a paid app.
- [iClink](http://www.companionlink.com/iphone)

  A third-party iPhone application that allows you to add/edit/delete tasks as well as calendar, contact, and note data. Syncs with other services such as Lotus Notes and GroupWise. Requires a desktop component: http://www.companionlink.com.
- [Tasks'n Notes](http://www.basisinformationtechnology.com/tasksnnotes/)
- [iExchangeEn](http://www.iexchange.1free.ws/)
- [iTaskPro](http://www.innov8tion.com/apps/itask/)

Answer (score 2):

TaskTask is the software you are looking for. 
Does just what you are asking for, works just like calendar sync and mail sync. The only tiny drawback is that it uses it's own authorization to the server, and you have to enter your exchange info once more.

Really good.

http://www.tasktaskonline.com/TaskTask/TaskTask.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm a sys admin at a medium size company and we use iMExchange [iphone apps](http://iphone.appspatrol.com/) to sync Exchange to iPhone. It's worked well for us so far and I recommend this option.

Answer (score 1):

I use NHSmail which is used throughout the UK National Health Service and is based on Exchange. It's security is very robust and OWA sync never works due to this. TaskTask does work however, and is the only task client that I have tried that works (I have tried dozens), and is very good to boot! The username has to be in the format with @nhs.net rather than just the prefix to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Todo® Exchange Tasks by Appigo](http://www.appigo.com/todo-exchange).

[image: Screenshot from Appigo website]